# preg_match second match

Tags: php, preg-match

Just trying to `preg_match` the second match.

```
<?php
$url = "http://domain.com";
preg_match('~<table([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']ladder-table["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</table>~i', file_get_contents($url), $match);
print $match[0];    
?>
```

Here is the table I'm trying to find:

```
<table class="ladder-table">Content</table>
<table class="ladder-table">Content</table> <-- [This one]
<table class="ladder-table">Content</table>
```

The last two tables are hidden by a java script code. Does it influence on the pattern?

Comment: preg_match only checks for a single match. You want preg_match_all :-)

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to continue to use regular expressions, use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$url = "http://domain.com";
preg_match_all('~<table([^>]*)(class\\s*=\\s*["\']ladder-table["\'])([^>]*)>(.*?)</table>~i', file_get_contents($url), $match);
print_r($match[0][1]);
```

This may be enough for your requirements. However, it's difficult to make your code robust enough to deal with changes to the HTML; for instance, the above wouldn't match if `Content` has any new lines, because you're checking for `.*?` without the `PCRE_DOTALL` modifier.

The correct way to handle this would be using a proper HTML parser such as [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) or [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).